# how can get last ID after UPDATING records?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to **UPDATE** many records in a database (which is ORACLE) using JDBC(OJDBC7) in Java. At the same time, I want to obtain the UPDATE ID. How can I achieve this using JDBC?

Comment: Why should the ID change after an update?

Comment: Do you want to obtain the generated IDs using a batch insert?

Comment: no change ID . for example : UPDATE COMPANY Set NAME= 'JIMI' WHERE NAME LIKE '%ARASH%';

Comment: You will have to make the select `SELECT ID FROM COMPANY WHERE NAME LIKE '%ARASH%'` first and then the update.

Comment: In JDBC, there is no better way?
JDBC can return to the field values of your ID WHICH CHANGES RECORD?

Comment: It could be easily done at database level in PL/SQL using **RETURNING INTO** clause. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472118/returning-the-value-of-identity-column-after-insertion-in-oracle and http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/07/returning-the-sequence-number-of-identity-column-after-insert/ Those examples are for an insert statement, but it works exactly same for an UPDATE statement too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your update statement looks something like:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_one = ? WHERE conditions
```

Selecting the ids of the updated rows could be done before updating using the same where conditions as the update. So first you do a select to get the ids

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE conditions
```

and then apply the update (based on ids for better performance)

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_one = ? WHERE id IN selected_ids
```